# How to use INSERT each row of a list to mySQL from Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list of data and need to insert each row back to MySQL. Below is an example of my data.

```
print(data[1:5])

[['Abilene, TX', 'Ahwatukee Foothills, AZ', 922.41258034], 
['Abilene, TX', 'Akron, OH', 1494.34762588], 
['Abilene, TX', 'Alafaya, FL', 1381.55219389], 
['Abilene, TX', 'Alameda, CA', 1680.9984747]]
```

My SQL columns are City, Destination, distance and so far I have:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO table Shark (City, Destination, Distance) VALUES (:data)",[i])
```

which gives me an error "Not all parameters were used in the SQL Statment". How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
data = [['Abilene, TX', 'Ahwatukee Foothills, AZ', 922.41258034], 
['Abilene, TX', 'Akron, OH', 1494.34762588], 
['Abilene, TX', 'Alafaya, FL', 1381.55219389], 
['Abilene, TX', 'Alameda, CA', 1680.9984747]]

for r in data:
    mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO table Shark (City, Destination, Distance) VALUES ({},{},{})".format(r[0], r[1], r[2])
```

Comment: It's still giving me issues. I think it's because there are commas between the city and the state.

Comment: so I changed it to r=0
for r in data:
    print('INSERT INTO mileage (SourceCity, Destination, Distance) VALUES ({''''},{''''},{});'.format(data[r][0], data[r][1], data[r][2])) to pick up r

Comment: and it's giving me a list indices must be integers or slices, not list error